# Proving that the Catalan numbers are integers .

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

So the nth catalan numbers is given by $$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n \choose n}$$

I want to prove now that $n+1$ divides ${2n \choose n}$ so I try to do it the following way $${2n \choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n-n)!} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!^2} = \frac{(2n)(2n-1)!}{(n(n-1)!)^2}$$

But still How can I conclude that $n+1$ divides ${2n \choose n}$ ?

Comment: It's right there on the wikipedia page for the Catalan numbers.

Comment: I know that but I still want to prove that $n+1$  divides ${2n \choose n}$

Comment: I mean, the proof is right there on the Wikipedia page.